Can I creat a line-plot chart with the height variable on the vertical axis and temperature values for three different sites on the horizontal axis?
I want to create a line-plot chart with the height on the vertical axis and temperature for three different sites on the horizontal axis. Pllease refer to the second image on the webpage below. This is what I want to create:
https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/part-b-vertical-temperature-profile-110-100-thermosphere-90-80-mesopause-figure-2-vertical-q56095924
I entered the values as follows in Google Sheet:
enter image description here
I want to plot vertical temperature profiles for Dry Adiabatic Line, Wet Adiabatic Line, site A, site B, and site C. But I try to create a chart with this table in Google Sheet, it gives me this one:
enter image description here
No, this is not that I want. I want to put height on the vertical axis and the temperatures on the horizontal axis.
How could you do this, please?
I know this can be done in Microsoft Excel with a few clicks but I have to use Google sheet.
Thanks in advance.
I tried search on the Internet but couldn't find any solution. I want to have the height variable on the vertical axis and the temperature variable on the horizontal axis.

Super User might be a better community for your question.
